# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 error

Tags: java, if-statement, try-catch

I'm trying to find all these elements and click them once they are found but faced this error of Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 and I'm not sure what my mistakes are.

```
            try {
                while(clickMore == true) {
                List<WebElement> commentsbutton = comment.findElements(By.className("UFIPagerLink"));
                List<WebElement> repliesbutton = comment.findElements(By.className("UFIReplySocialSentenceLinkText"));
                List<WebElement> seemorebutton = comment.findElements(By.className("_1n4g"));
                if(commentsbutton.size() > 0 || repliesbutton.size() > 0 || seemorebutton.size() > 0 ) {
                    commentsbutton.get(0).click();
                    repliesbutton.get(0).click();
                    seemorebutton.get(0).click();
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                }
                else clickMore = false;
                } 
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                System.out.println("Elements in this post not found");
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

That clearly saying that your `commentsbutton` is empty and no elements in it. But you are trying to get element at index `0` which is not there.

You have to consider changing your if condition such that it avoid the exception.

Comment: If `commentsbutton.size() > 0`, then shouldn't it be safe to call `commentsbutton.get(0)`?

Comment: @dave: Note the `||` following it

Comment: D'oh. Just saw that :(

Answer (score 3):

Your condition is wrong. Your can only access `commentsbutton.get(0)` safely if `commentsbutton.size() > 0`.

Change it to :

```
            if(commentsbutton.size() > 0 && repliesbutton.size() > 0 && seemorebutton.size() > 0 ) {
                commentsbutton.get(0).click();
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            }
```

or

```
            if(commentsbutton.size() > 0) {
                commentsbutton.get(0).click();
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            }
```

depending on the required logic.

Answer (score 1):

`||` means "or", so this code:

```
if(commentsbutton.size() > 0 || repliesbutton.size() > 0 || seemorebutton.size() > 0 ) {
    commentsbutton.get(0).click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
}
```

...says "if `commentsbutton`'s size is > 0 ***or*** `repliesbutton`'s size > 0 ***or*** `seemorebutton`'s size > 0, get the first item from `commentsbutton`." So what if `commentsbutton` is empty but `repliesbutton` has something in it? You'll get the error you're getting.

You may have meant `&&` ("and") rather than `||` ("or"), or you may have just wanted to check `commentsbutton` and not the others.

Comment: I wanted to check all three buttons for instance as long as any one of the button exists, there is a click. please look at my edited question. thank you.

Comment: @dark_space: Again, you can't access the first entry in `commentsbutton` *if it doesn't have one*. Your condition is an "or". It may be that you want to check them individually, I can't tell from the code you've posted. But this is basic logic: You'll go into your `if` block if **any** of those conditions is true, because you've used "or."

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an `or` condition before you try to access the `first` element in the `list`

```
if(commentsbutton.size() > 0 || repliesbutton.size() > 0 || seemorebutton.size() > 0 )
```

In this case, since its an `or` condition, only one of the condition has to be `true` for the block to get executed.

Either change it to `and` condition or just check for `size` only for `commentsButton` before trying to access the element.